# Laravel Missing required parameters

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes

I tried to create a new route with a controller that uses an id parameter, and a link to this.
The error is when I try to create a link to a controller.
The error that I got is:

> "Missing required parameters for [Route: notas.detalle] [URI: detalle/{id}]. (View: /var/www/html/laravel/blog/resources/views/producto.blade.php)"

The route:

```php
Route::get('detalle/{id}', 'productoController@detalle')>name('notas.detalle');
```

The blade template:

```html
@foreach($notas as $nota)
    <a href="{{ route('notas.detalle'), $nota }}">{{$nota->id}}</a>
    {{$nota->created_at}}
    {{$nota->updated_at}}
@endforeach
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: You have a typo - the `$nota` variable is outside the function parenthesis. `route('notas.detalle'), $nota` should be `route('notas.detalle', $nota)`

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to the issue being a typo.

Comment: @Qirel thnaks! that was the error.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel route helpers can take as a second parameter, an associative array with all the keys (require parameter) and it values.

so is your case it would be something like this

```
route('notas.detalle', ['id' => 1])
```

but it could be multiple parameter so is your route had something like 'notas/{id}/student/{student}

then you could do the following.

```
route('notas.detalle', ['id' => 1, student => 129483])
```

here is a link to the docs where you can see this in more details.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable must be after comma. 
I think this will work:

```
<a href="{{ route('notas.detalle', $nota->id) }}">{{$nota->id}}</a>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why* you think that will work? A good answer always includes a descriptive text on why this solves the issue.